# Usando tkinter, al dar click en un objeto entry, ¿Como hacer para que me aparezca un teclado para llenar esa entrada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy haciendo una interfaz en Python usando tkinter, la cuestión es que la aplicación no debe hacer uso de un teclado externo (hardware), ya que en este caso solo tendré una pantalla touch, por lo mismo, necesito que de alguna forma pueda introducir al menos números a el objeto entrada, lo que se me había ocurrido es hacer algo similar a algunos programas, que das click y te aparece un teclado para escribir, sea únicamente numérico o que tenga más teclas.

Mi código es tan simple como:

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
top.mainloop()
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda

Comment: Hola muunzoon, por favor comenta esto, desarrolle algo asi para un raspberry, pero el codigo lo tengo en la pc del trabajo, mañana en la mañana te comento el codigo, solo que no se pierda la publicacion

Comment: Agradeceria mucho si me hecharas la mano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien intentare explicar un poco esto

No es como tal pero funciona,

Puedes mostrar estoy como una funcion de tkinter,

```
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("620x330")
        self.codigoempleado = []

        btns_frame = Frame(self.master, width=312, height=272.5, bg="grey")
        btns_frame.pack()

        Button(btns_frame, text="7", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(7)).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="8", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(8)).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="9", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(9)).grid(row=1, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="4", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(4)).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="5", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(5)).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="6", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(6)).grid(row=2, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="1", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(1)).grid(row=3, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="2", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(2)).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="3", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(3)).grid(row=3, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="0", fg="black", width=23, height=3, bd=0, bg="#fff",
               cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_click(0)).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=1, pady=1)
        Button(btns_frame, text="Aceptar", fg="black", width=10, height=3, bd=0,
               bg="#eee", cursor="hand2", command=lambda: self.btn_equal()).grid(row=4, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
```

Aqui lo que intente simular fue una calculadora, no se si sea la mejor forma pero va

Creamos nuestro frame,
luego nuestros botones, todo simple y sencillo, al dar click en cada una de las "teclas" vamos agregando el valor numerico a una lista, (aunque se que lamdba como tal no deberia ir, por alguna razon no me funciona si no lo agrego, ya que lamdba hace una funcion anonima y regresa el nombre de la funcion como valor,

al final lo que hago es convertir esa lista en string

```
def btn_click(self, item):
        self.codigoempleado.append(item)
        print(self.codigoempleado)

    def btn_equal(self):
        employeednum = self.listToString(self.codigoempleado[0:99])
        self.consultEmployeed(employeednum)
        self.codigoempleado = []

    def listToString(self, result):
        strcodigo = ""
        for ele in result:
            strcodigo += str(ele)

        return strcodigo

    def consultEmployeed(self, codigo):
        print(codigo)
```

Esto lo puedes agregar a tkinter, que al momento de que des click crear una nueva ventana con un toplevel y ahi agregar el codigo que muestro.